# How to make a change within nested data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I got this:

```
type ID = Int

data Bank = Bank [(ID, Account)] deriving Show

data Account = Account
  { balance :: Int
  , owner :: Client
  } deriving Show

data Client = Client
  { name :: String
  , surname :: String
  , address :: String
  } deriving Show
```

my task is, to write a function `credit :: Int -> ID -> Bank -> Bank`
that Adds the specified amount of Money to the specified amount
Account.
I do not know how can i actually do that, because these are data types..

Comment: What do you mean by "because these are data types"?

Comment: i do know how to create data types, but add some money to some accounts sounds for me really complex. i do not really know can i do that

Comment: Well instead of starting with writing complex functions, you perhaps first should start writing more simple ones. For instance try to fetch the balance of a given `ID` from a given bank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you defined `Account` using record syntax, we're going to use record syntax again to make a change to an account.

How to modify an `Account` to add money to it:

```
creditAccount :: Int -> Account -> Account
creditAccount amount acct = acct { balance = balance acct + amount }
```

To modify a `Bank`, we're going to destructure it using a pattern match to get at the underlying list of `accounts`, then use the `Bank` constructor to lift the resulting list back into the `Bank` type.

How to modify a `Bank` by making a modification to a particular account:

```
modifyAccount :: ID -> (Account -> Account) -> Bank -> Bank
modifyAccount i f (Bank accounts) = Bank (map g accounts)
  where 
    g (i', acct) = (i', if i == i' then f acct else acct)
```

Putting it together, how to modify a `Bank` by crediting a particular account:

```
credit :: Int -> ID -> Bank -> Bank
credit amount i = modifyAccount i (creditAccount amount)
```

Comment: ty very much sir. explained it really clearly